# How to center a Textbox inside a Border in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my `WP7` app, I am creating a `Textbox` inside a `Border`. How to align the `Textbox` exactly at the center of the `Border`?

```
         Border rectangleborder = new Border();
         rectangleborder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
         rectangleborder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
         rectangleborder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
         rectangleborder.Width = width;
         rectangleborder.Height = width;
         TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
         textbox.Text = "1";
         textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
         textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
         textbox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
         this.canvas1.Children.Add(rectangleborder);
         rectangleborder.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 30 + (j - 1) * width);
         rectangleborder.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 30 + (i - 1) * width);
         rectangleborder.Child = textbox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set the `HorizontalAlignment` to align horizontally and the `VerticalAlignment` to align vertically:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

And the result should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
  TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
  textbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
  textbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

You can also allign the text inside using:-

```
     textBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```